# Flutter Web Disable Mouse Context Menu Widget

Tags: flutter, widget, contextmenu, flutter-web

Is there a way to disable the right click context menu in Flutter Web on a browser for a specific Widget only?

Sure that I can disable it for the whole site by going into index.html and disable it in the body tag.

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

Not so sure how I would do it for only a specific widget on screen if there is any way?

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm able to disable right click in whole page

Comment: I can't believe it that even after 2 years it is not possible to do this... I currently need to disable it on my custom context menu items and have it enabled when copying and pasting text, since trying to make a custom copy paste system on TextFormField seems to be broken on so many levels in web when using mobile devices.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78177912/3808307 This solution doesn't disable it for just a widget, but it disables when clicking that widget and re enables it afterwards. Maybe it's useful to you

Answer (score 0):

Wow I finally figured out a hacky way to disable context menu on specific widgets. Idea is simple, just use bool value and toggle that on right click and after the context menu check has happened. Here is an example widget which creates a right clickable text widget that disables right click context menu only on this widget:

```
// Remember to add dependency to 'universal_html: ^2.0.8'
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;

class PreventLinkContext extends StatefulWidget {
  const PreventLinkContext({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PreventLinkContext> createState() => _PreventLinkContextState();
}

class _PreventLinkContextState extends State<PreventLinkContext> {
  bool linkClicked = false;

  var _preventContextMenu;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _preventContextMenu = (html.Event event) => {
          if (linkClicked)
            {
              event.preventDefault(),
              linkClicked = false,
            }
        };

    html.document.addEventListener('contextmenu', _preventContextMenu);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    html.document.removeEventListener('contextmenu', _preventContextMenu);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onSecondaryTap: () {
        linkClicked = true;
      },
      child: const Text(
        'Link',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.cyan,
          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: Added removeEventListener to dispose function and information about universal_html package.